# xhttp.responseText returning an empty string

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to retrieve data(string) from a flask server with the a GET request and the
xhttp.responseText is always an empty string.

Here is my python code

[image]

Here is my Html code

[image]

edit:
console tab says: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Also look in the console and network tab for errors

Comment: the console tab says: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I am not really sure what this mean

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your backend needs to return proper CORS headers, like the Access-Control-Allow-Origin mentioned in the error.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i

Answer (score -1):

Instead of triggering the GET from your front-end, can you build the same GET request in Postman and check if it still returns an empty string? (i.e. as a way to debug the issue)

See: [Building requests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/)

Comment: I built the same GET request in postman and it still return an empty string.

Comment: Can you inspect the GET request details in Postman and check what the `Origin` field is?

Also, in the server's HTTP response, do you see a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field? What is it set to?

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at '127.0.0.1:5000' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: @mplungjan - thanks for pointing that out.